# QWebView(QUrl()) doesn't work - Python 2.7

Tags: python, pyqt4, qwebview

I'am running into trouble with the following code :

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.fr"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run it with my python3 interpreter it works perfectly fine, however when I run it with python 2 "the process finish with exit code -1073740940".

I've checked the documentation and it seems to be compatible with python 2.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Please state the platform you are on, and also the exact versions of python, pyqt and qt you are using.

Comment: @Naxx17 : I ran the above given code in Python 2.7.6 and the code works perfectly.